# Vulkan: In the case of multiple frame buffer, should I create multiple VkBuffers for each shader uniform?

Tags: vulkan

glsl:

```
#version 450

layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform mat4 MyMatrix;

void main() {
}
```

If multiple frame buffers are in progress, multiple frame buffers may be submitted to the queue at the same time, for example:

```
while(!isClose) {
    ...
    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> cs = {commandBuffers[imageIndex]}; // bind different frame buffer
    ...
    vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[currentFrame]);
    ...
    currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
    ...
}
```

MyMatrix needs to update every frame. If MyMatrix uses the same VkBuffer, every frame of data may be overwritten? So should I create multiple VkBuffers for MyMatrix?

Comment: Once you untangle the "multiple frame buffer" thing, what you're talking about is just standard Vulkan synchronization. You cannot modify memory that is potentially being used, so unless you synchronize your modifications of that memory with the actions that use it, you cannot perform that modification.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple buffers is probably overkill - it's more usual to allocate a single large uniform buffer and then sub-allocate from that for each draw call batch. You can then just use offsets into that buffer for each draw, rather than needing an entire new buffer each time.

In general offsets are less expensive for hardware to handle than entirely new buffer descriptors.

Comment: In other words, as the multiple frame buffer increases, I need to apply for a larger VkBuffer for the uniform that updates the data for each frame？

Comment: In general memory is "cheap" so allocate a larger buffer than you think you need; if you don't use it it is unlikely to cause problems. You can have multiple "large" buffers if you run out of space in one.